# Putting a stacked bar into a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I've got a large dataframe and each row has a count of the number of good, okay, bad and other events against it.

I'm trying to replace those 4 columns with a single column that visually represents the same data. i.e. I'd like to replace 4 cells with a single cell containing a stacked horizontal bar

So I want my table to look like the above rather than the like the bottom
[image]

I've struggling with the python thus far as the only route I can think of combining them would be to generate each bar seperately in matplotlib, export to jpg and then import into the dataframe.
Which feels like it won't be scaleable...

[image: Fig 1]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm confused here. Are you trying to store a visual image in one of the columns of your dataframe? (Pandas isn't really intended for that!) If that is the case, however, why not simply have a function that accepts your columns and returns your image when you need it.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm trying to do. So store an image in a column, then print it out for a report. I'm not sure if there is a better tool for me to use however.